# How to create and assign access to a user via Maxl?

Tags: hyperion, essbase, sharedservices

Hyperion shared services is not working properly so how can I create and assign an LDAP user access to cubes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the user exists in shared services by running below Maxl command in EAS console.

> display user "z107818@SameTimeLdap";

if user doesn't exist, it will throw a warning, as shown in the
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1GOJ.jpg)

2. Now create a user in shared services using the below command.

> create user "z107818@SameTimeLdap" type external;

Its cause the user exists in LDAP, that's why type is external

3. Now grant access to essbase cubes via below command

> grant read on database LncSum.LncSum to "z107818";

For more info on this read below Oracle article.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/maxl_creusr.html